# Block user after 6 month of inactivity

Tags: users

I want to block the user who does not logged in the application since six month.

Comment: What did you try? What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Simple que..When user is not logged in the application within six month and after six month when he/she try to log in .The user will automatically block and can only be unblock by the administrator

Comment: What did **you** try to solve the issue? If you haven't already, dig around the problem yourself and post back when you have a specific issue. When you just ask people to provide you with a solution and show no initiative, you show no respect to people that could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [Inactive User](https://www.drupal.org/project/inactive_user).

> The inactive_user module provides Drupal administrators with a way to automatically manage inactive user accounts. This module has two goals: to help keep users coming back to your site by reminding them when they've been away for a configurable period of time, and to cleanup unused accounts.

(It is marked as "Unsupported" - but it does the job.)

A more stable module is [User expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_expire).

> This module allows an administrator to define a date on which to expire a specific user account. Use cases for this include anytime a user (such as contractors or short-term employee) are only active for a set period of time until their Drupal account should be disabled. This best fits when different users have unique expiration timeframes.

But it is not an exact match for your use case, since I understand that you want to have an automatic default six month expiry period.

Comment: THanks for the help ..Yes i am asking for the automatic default six month expiry period..SO Inactive_user will do the job thanks once again.:)

Comment: I would personally use User Expire. It seems more widely used and has more interesting features, including expiring the user: "You want to lock accounts if a user is inactive for a period of days, like 90 days. (e.g. for PCI Compliance)"